# Reference list is not generating

Tags: bibtex

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2022)
The top-level auxiliary file: gas_diffusion.aux
I couldn't open style file strbib.bst ---line 2 of file gas_diffusion.aux :
   \bibstyle{strbib : }
  I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 68 of file gas_diffusion.aux :
  \bibstyle : {plain}
  I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file gas_diffusion.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you have two `\bibliographystyle` commands in your document, one of which refers to a style file that isn't accessible to bibtex (`strbib.bst`).